# Angular Material md-checkbox required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a group of checkboxes which are the days of the week. If the user clicks the submit button and no checkboxes have been checked, I want to display an error message. Below is the HTML code I'm using.

```
<form id="addEditForm" name="addEditForm" ng-submit="addEditForm.$valid && saveBooking()" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="item in days">
        <md-checkbox ng-required="daysSelected.length == 0" ng-checked="dayExists(item, daysSelected)" ng-click="toggleWeekdays(item, daysSelected)" name="daysOfWeek">{{ item }}</md-checkbox>
    </div>

    <div flex ng-messages="addEditForm.daysOfWeek.$error" ng-if="addEditForm.$submitted">
        <div ng-message="required">Please select a day.</div>
    </div>

    <md-button aria-label="Save Booking" class="md-primary-short" type="submit" >Save</md-button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have no `submit` in your example, but I would assume that there is one somewhere below in your HTTP code.

What I would advise you is to use [the Dialog directive](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) to display your message, from your controller. You can check if your item list has the expected length (with the logic you already implemented I guess), and display the message if it does not fill the conditions.

---

**EDIT**

So I would add some kind of an oracle in your controller, like:
`$scope.sentinel = []`

When you check a box, you just add its value to the `sentinel` value:

`$scope.sentinel.push(yourValue)`

Then, when you click the `submit` button, you just check for its length:

```
if ($scope.sentinel.length == 0) {
  $scope.displayError = true;
}
```

This is the simplest way I thought of. Do not forget to initialize your `$scope.displayError` variable to `false` and put it back to `true` when your condition is met.

Comment: I've updated code with submit button. I want the error message inline as I have other fields (which I've omitted here) that can have error messages too.

Comment: Edited the question, try it ! :)